# Block access to all URL patterns containting /feed/

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

We have an issue where spammers are subscribing to all our feeds.
I already disabled all feeds via a function, as well as using a plugin.

Each day they still appear in our logs with thousands of entries.
For example:

```
/leaderboard/feed/index.php
/leaderboard/feed/
/some-category/feed/
```

Is there any way to block access to all visitors querying  /feed/ or anything containing the word "feed" in the URL via .htaccess, and deny them access to the site?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes rewrite rules can do that:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^feed/ - [NC,F]
```

This will give forbidden error for every URI that starts with `/feed/`